# How to know when async query's finished

Tags: sharepoint-server, query

When does an asynchronus function end in case I want to show the user a "saving" icon when the query's proceeding?

I have something like this for my query:

```
entry = webList.addItem(entryCreationInformation);
entry.set_item("JobCode", jobCode);
entry.set_item("ClientName", prestation);
entry.set_item("DateMonth", dateMonth);
entry.set_item("Heure",heure);
entry.update();
context.load(entry);
context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
```

I'm adding up to 50 items one by one with this method, so I have a success event for each one of them.

I want to show the loading icon during all the process and then remove it when all the items were inserted.

Sometimes I make updates too:

```
var clientContext = context;
var oList = webList;

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(parseInt(id));

oListItem.set_item("JobCode", jobCode);
oListItem.set_item("ClientName", clientName);
oListItem.set_item("DateMonth", date);
oListItem.set_item("Heure", heure);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

And the update references another method as the success method.

Is there a possibility to know when the server have finished doing the current user queries?

Comment: You know the count of items to be added and updated right?

Comment: I don't know how many items will there be. But i know when the query is fired. What i can do as suggested below is to increment 2 variable, one on query fired and the second one on query success and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very basic solution but what I did was create a variable where I coun't the amount of events fired. A second one that counts the events completed, and then just add an if block in my success function with logic to hide the loading dialog when the 2 variables are equal.

Comment: Oh, i see what you did there. I will ry that if there's no better solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling context.executeQueryAsync for each item, just add the up to 50 items, then call context.executeQueryAsync after the last one and when the callback is called you're done.

Comment: This is indeed a better solution, but when using these apps on sharepoint online you'll hit the max amount of loads you can do in 1 query pretty fast.